# Error parsing JSON android when use class method

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

Hi I'm working with android `Volley` to get `JSON`from the server then parse it to object. I'm trying to create a class with a method to parse JSON response. My URL are for example: `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/11544988.json?print=pretty`

here is my class method (in `TopStory.java`)

```
public static TopStory fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        TopStory topStory = new TopStory();

        // Deserialize json into object fields
        try {
            topStory.id = jsonObject.getInt(Constant.TAG_ID);
            topStory.title = jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_TITLE);
            topStory.author = jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_AUTHOR);
            topStory.timestamp = jsonObject.getInt(Constant.TAG_TIMESTAMP);
            topStory.url=jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_URL);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // Return new object
        return topStory;
    }
```

in the MainActivity. I use Volley to get the response and use class method to parse it to object. I can get the response (can make a Toast to display) but got error when parsing: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.vic.hackernew.Model.TopStory.getAuthor()' on a null object reference`. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

```
private void getTopStoryDetail(RequestQueue requestQueue, String topStoryUrl) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CustomJsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,topStoryUrl,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject respond) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),respond.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        TopStory topStory = TopStory.fromJson(respond);

                        topStories.add(topStory);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), topStory.getAuthor(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

my entire `TopStory.java`

```
package com.vic.hackernew.Model;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vic.hackernew.Utils.Constant;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by vic on 21-Apr-16.
 */
public class TopStory {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int score;
    private int[] kids;
    private int timestamp;
    private String url;

    public TopStory() {
    }

    public TopStory(int id, String title, String author, int point, int timestamp,String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.score = point;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(int timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int[] getKids() {
        return kids;
    }

    public void setKids(int[] kids) {
        this.kids = kids;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    // Decodes business json into business model object
    public static TopStory fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        TopStory topStory = new TopStory();

        // Deserialize json into object fields
        try {
            topStory.id = jsonObject.getInt(Constant.TAG_ID);
            topStory.title = jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_TITLE);
            topStory.author = jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_AUTHOR);
            topStory.timestamp = jsonObject.getInt(Constant.TAG_TIMESTAMP);
            topStory.url=jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_URL);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // Return new object
        return topStory;
    }
```

My `Constanst.java`

```
public class Constant {
    public static String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    public static String TAG_AUTHOR = "by";
    public static String TAG_KIDS = "kids";
    public static String TAG_SCORE = "point";
    public static String TAG_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static String TAG_URL = "url";

    public static String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
    public static String TAG_BASE_URL = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/";
    public static String TAG_TOPSTORIES_URL = "topstories.json";
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)? It's much easier to work with

Comment: post your model class

Comment: Hi, I've add my entire TopStory.java

Comment: How to use Gson to achieve the same result? I just want to parse the JsonObjectResoponse to store on the model. Thanks

Comment: in your response probably you are not getting any author field. that's why its set to null. please put null pointer check & check Constants.TAG_AUTHOR. Is it same as per your response? It's better to debug why this is happening.

Comment: Gson converts JSON directly to a model class in one line of code, thus easier.

Comment: Try to debug fromJson method. As I see from error this method return null

Comment: your json response doesn't contain author field

Comment: hi How to  put null pointer check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just paste this line in parsing

```
topStory.author = jsonObject.optString(Constant.TAG_AUTHOR);
```

instead of

```
topStory.author = jsonObject.getString(Constant.TAG_AUTHOR);
```

if this solves your problem then problem was within your response with some item's url.

So in looked upon the json you are receieving it is

```
{

    "by": "maibaum",
    "descendants": ​156,
    "id": ​11544988,
    "kids": 

    [
        ​11545261,
        ​11546393,
        ​11545187,
        ​11546084,
        ​11545168,
        ​11546078,
        ​11545846,
        ​11546650,
        ​11545285,
        ​11545262,
        ​11545178,
        ​11546996,
        ​11545394,
        ​11546690,
        ​11546275,
        ​11545336,
        ​11545515,
        ​11545127,
        ​11546000,
        ​11546043,
        ​11546842,
        ​11546025,
        ​11546221,
        ​11545281,
        ​11545142,
        ​11546502,
        ​11546215,
        ​11546070,
        ​11546257,
        ​11546258,
        ​11545195
    ],
    "score": ​238,
    "time": ​1461269223,
    "title": "FBI Paid More Than $1M to Hack San Bernardino iPhone",
    "type": "story",
    "url": "http://www.wsj.com/articles/comey-fbi-paid-more-than-1-million-to-hack-san-bernardino-iphone-1461266641"

}
```

if you look into it you won't find any author field. That's why you are gettting null. Also i see "by" in this response if it is the author then you should change your Constant.Author to "by" instead of "author" this may solve your problem.
I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I think not the prob. my Constant.TAG_AUTHOR="by". I can get author by  try {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),respond.getString(Constant.TAG_AUTHOR), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

Comment: paste the Constants class

Comment: Hi ive add the constanst.java on the question

Comment: Now please share the actual url here. Code looks fine. maybe you are getting authorfield null by response. Don't share example url

Comment: Hi the request is base on item in another request: my method: getTopStoryDetail(requestQueue,(Constant.TAG_BASE_URL+"item/"+respond.getInt(i)+".json?print=pretty"));  I can parse the response directly but not through class method

Comment: Thanks it work by change to topStory.author = jsonObject.optString(Constant.TAG_AUTHOR); what the different between optString and getString?